# Undefined reference to vtable when in one translation unit

Tags: c++, qt

I just want to start a simple QT application.  I have `main.cpp`, `mainwindow.h` and `mainwindow.cpp`.  This works, however, when I copy and paste the code from `mainwindow.h` and `mainwindow.cpp` into `main.cpp`, I get mysterious linker errors.

### WHAT WORKS

```cpp
// mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT
public:
        MainWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
        ~MainWindow();
private:
        Ui::MainWindow* ui; 
};
#endif
```

```cpp
//mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
        ui = new Ui::MainWindow;
        ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; }
```

```cpp
//main.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow w;
        w.show();
        return a.exec();
}
```

### WHAT DOES NOT WORK

```cpp
//main.cpp
#include <QApplication>

#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT
public:
        MainWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
        ~MainWindow();
private:
        Ui::MainWindow* ui; 
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
        ui = new Ui::MainWindow;
        ui->setupUi(this);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow w;
        w.show();
        return a.exec();
}
```

This gives me the following errors during linking:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccX909s9.ltrans1.ltrans.o: in function `MainWindow::~MainWindow()':
<artificial>:(.text+0x3): undefined reference to `vtable for MainWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccX909s9.ltrans1.ltrans.o: in function `main':
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x4a): undefined reference to `vtable for MainWindow'
```

After some searching around, that very detailed error means there is a virtual function  somewhere that is not implemented.  I'm really struggling to see how any of this matters here.

For reference, I'm a traditionally a C programmer, and from my perspective, these programs should be identical. I would really love to understand what magic gibberish the compiler is looking for at this point.

Comment: How sure are you that mainwindow.cpp is in the project and being compiled? Vandalize the file so that it can't be compiled and see if you get the appropriate error messages.

Comment: @user4581301 Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but in `main.cpp` at the top, I'm trying to compile that by itself which gives the error.  When I split it into `main.cpp`, `mainwindow.cpp` and `mainwindow.h`, it works.  But from a C perspective, these are the same program...

Comment: @Jason *"Maybe I'm not understanding the question,"* -- Correct, you missed the point. The suggestion was to do something like replace `#include "ui_mainwindow.h"` with `#include "ThisFileBetterNotExistBecauseINeedCompilationToFail.NotAHeader"`, then re-compile to verify that the error message changes. This would verify that you are compiling what you think you are compiling.

Comment: Does `MainWindow` go through moc compilation in the first case?

Comment: @JaMiT Question has been edited.  Also lol, `main.cpp:6:10: fatal error: 'ThisFileBetterNotExistBecauseINeedCompilationToFail.NotAHeader' file not found`

Comment: @Atmo It does not.  It just compiles `main.cpp` and goes right into linking.

Comment: @Jason Good, that rules out the most likely suspect. (In case you haven't guessed, your analysis appears to be correct. That's why we started looking at non-code explanations.)

Comment: And of course, I suppose your .h file does go through moc... If your first snippet does not moc your class, then wouldn't that mean that the `metaObject` method declared in the `Q_OBJECT` macro, which is virtual, is not being implemented? I believe the macro was unnecessary in your case, since you declare no property, signal or slot for your `MainWindow` class, nor use its metaobject. What happens if you remove it and retry?

Comment: Apologies. I read the question backwards. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @Atmo, I think you got it.  On my machine, there are 3 virtual functions defined as part of Q_OBJECT macro.  I have to delete all 3 in order to not get the error.  I tried `qmake -nomoc`, but still get the error.  So, it would seem this is more of a limitation of QT?  It must have each of the Q_OBJECT objects moc'd and in their own files or something.

Comment: "*It must have each of the Q_OBJECT moc'd*" -> Unless you want to manually type an implementation for the virtual methods, yes. I am not a C programmer but I would expect the same goes for a C program with functions declared but not defined. "*in their own files or something*" -> Not sure that is the case but I think it is cleaner if you put each class in its own header.

Comment: Hehe, At least a C compiler would say `undefined reference to foo`.  I'd disagree about each class in it's own header, but as a C guy, I think classes are dumb so my opinion is irrelevant. If you to make that solution an answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes classes are dumb. People over-use them almost as much as they underuse them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was clarified in comments, the 2 programs are in fact not identical: in the first case, nothing is creating the methods hidden inside the `Q_OBJECT` macro, some of which are virtual (`metaObject` is the most important one there). This is supposed to be the role of `moc` (Meta-object compiler).
What you get is virtual methods declared but not implemented.

Unlike the above, your header+source files approach does cause the header file to be moc'd, which creates a separate source file with the required methods.
In Qt creator or in Visual studio with the Qt VS tools extension installed, everything happens automatically; that is no action from you is required to configure the steps (it may be the case in other development environments).
In Visual studio vanilla (the only environment I ever used Qt with manually configuring everything), you would have to configure a custom build step manually, then include the generated source file for it to be compiled. Configuring everything manually is a bit of a headache but that would have allowed you to easily tell the mistake.

---

Note: As I said in comments, the `Q_OBJECT` macro is not a mandatory thing for subclasses of `QObject`. If you do not declare anything that would modify the class' meta-object (signals, slots, properties, interface, ...), then the macro can be skipped.

AFAICT, the code in your question does not need `Q_OBJECT`, hence the main.cpp-only snippet in your question should work after you simply remove it.

Comment: Ha, I just realized where the disconnect was.. I thought moc files were unit test files. I was just ignoring them.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually explained in https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/moc.html
and
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html#including-header-moc-files-in-sources

Summa summarum, as others have pointed out, the build system automatically generates and builds the right kind of additional source files for Q_OBJECT declarations in header files, but for Q_OBJECT declarations in source files, you need to include the generated MOC code in your source file to build it.